# Firebase RTDB Search for a keyword in a list of keywords

Tags: firebase, flutter, search, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase RTDB to access my data using the Flutter app.
The data has the following attributes:

```
{
  'Category': 'Food',
  'Product Description': 'Energy Drink',
  'Product Picture': 'image_link',
  'Product Title': 'Coca Cola',
  'Price': 40000,
  'inStock': 1,
  'keywords':[
    'coco cola',
    'energy drink',
    'drink',
    'other keywords'
  ]
}
```

I would like to use the keywords field to search for a specific product. How can I do that?

I know about 'orderby' and 'equalto' keywords in Firebase RTDB but how to use it with a list?

Or how do I change the structure of the data so that I can efficiently search for specific keywords?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Have you found anything useful?

Answer (score 1):

Store the keywords as maps. So it would be like `keywords: {'coca cola':true, ...}`

Then you can do

```
.orderBy('keywords/coca cola').equalTo(true)
```